# Apply constant-value MATLAB function to array

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, symbolic-math

Assume I generate MATLAB function using symbolic expression, which sometimes can be a constant. For example, if I compute gradient of different curves, one of the vector components can be a number:

```
syms x y;
expr = x^2 - 4*y;
grad = gradient(expr, [x, y]);

grad_func = matlabFunction(grad, 'Vars', [x, y]);
```

Assume that I want to apply this to an array of points. Is there a way to make generated MATLAB function robust enough to always return an array of the same size as input, even if original analytical expression (or a certain component of it) was a constant?

I try the following:

```
X = [-1:0.2:1]; 
Y = [-1:0.2:1];
[Gx, Gy] = grad_func(X,Y);
```

but get the error:

> Error using vertcat
>
> Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
>
> Error in symengine>makeFhandle/@(x,y)[x.*2.0;-4.0]

---

I also tried to use ARRAYFUN:

```
[Gx, Gy] = arrayfun(grad_func,X,Y);
```

but failed as well:

> The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side.
>
> Error in symengine>makeFhandle/@(x,y)[x.*2.0;-4.0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you do the array function

```
 g = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y) grad_func(x,y), X(:)',Y(:)', 'uni', 0));
 Gx = reshape(g(1, :), size(X));
 Gy = reshape(g(2, :), size(Y));
```